# Sum array of objects value based on month - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, chart.js

So first of all, because I am using a `ChartJS` I need to generate an array of months.
The creation is looking like this :

```
const [generatedMonths, setGeneratedMonths] = useState<string[]>([])
const [totalValues, setTotalValues] = useState<number[]>([])

const months = []
const dateStart = moment()
const dateEnd = moment().subtract(11, 'month')

while (dateEnd.isBefore(dateStart, 'day')) {
    months.push(dateEnd.format('MMM'))
    dateEnd.add(1, 'month')
}
months.push(dateEnd.format('MMM'))

setGeneratedMonths(months)
```

After that i receive my data like this :

```
  const myArray = [
    {date: "2022-04-13", vat_percentages: {21: 92.31}, total: 92.31}
    {date: "2022-05-04", vat_percentages: {21: 21.24}, total: 21.24}
    {date: "2022-05-05", vat_percentages: {21: 47.41}, total: 47.41}
    ]
```

Then in my `useEffect` hook i am performing the sum :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (myArray.length > 0) {
        const labelValues: number[] = generatedMonths.map(
            (label, index) => {
                const result = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    const foundItem = acc.find(
                        (item) => item.date.format('MMM') === label
                    )

                    if (foundItem) {
                        foundItem.total += curr.total
                    } else {
                        acc.push(curr)
                    }

                    return acc
                }, [])
            }
        )

      setTotalValues(labelValues)
    }


},[myArray])
```

So the final idea would be to have a sum for each month based on my find method based on the `total` value. Like this:

```
console.log(totalValues)
// [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 92.31, 68.65]
```

Comment: @Mushroomator if i use `map` function than i cannot apply the `find` method in my next scope. So thats why i think i went with `reduce()`

Answer (score 1):

You can massively simplify the solution using the fact that values for month are always going to be between 1-12 (inclusive). Therefore you can use an array of length 12 and use `month - 1` as an index to update the sum for a given month.

```js
const myArray = [{
  date: "2022-04-13",
  vat_percentages: {
    21: 92.31
  },
  total: 92.31
}, {
  date: "2022-05-04",
  vat_percentages: {
    21: 21.24
  },
  total: 21.24
}, {
  date: "2022-05-05",
  vat_percentages: {
    21: 47.41
  },
  total: 47.41
}]

const labelValues = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // parse a month to number e.g. "04" => 4 then substract 1 to get the index within the array 4 - 1 => 3
  const idx = Number(curr.date.split("-")[1]) - 1;
  acc[idx] += curr.total;
  return acc
}, new Array(12).fill(0))

console.log(labelValues)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The output should be interpreted as follows:

| 0 (Jan) | 1 (Feb) | 2 (Mar) | 3 (Apr) | 4 (May) | 5 (Jun) | 6 (Jul) | 7 (Aug) | 8 (Sep) | 9 (Oct) | 10 (Nov) | 11 (De) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 92.31 | 68.64999999999999 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

#### Edit

To reflect your requirement of having to set the values at certain positions according to `generatedMonths` you could use simple [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

A position for a month is therefore obtained by `(month + shiftValue) % 12`. To determine the shift value you just need to look at the first value in `generatedMonths` and lookup which month of the year that is.
The rest works exactly like before:

```js
const myArray = [{
  date: "2022-04-13",
  vat_percentages: {
    21: 92.31
  },
  total: 92.31
}, {
  date: "2022-05-04",
  vat_percentages: {
    21: 21.24
  },
  total: 21.24
}, {
  date: "2022-05-05",
  vat_percentages: {
    21: 47.41
  },
  total: 47.41
}]

// mapping of month to shift value
const mapping = {
  Jan: 0,
  Feb: 11,
  Mar: 10,
  Apr: 9,
  May: 8,
  Jun: 7,
  Jul: 6,
  Aug: 5,
  Sep: 4,
  Oct: 3,
  Nov: 2,
  Dec: 1
};
// compute a shift value
const generatedMonths = ["Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
const shiftBy = mapping[generatedMonths[0]];
const labelValues = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // parse a month to number e.g. "04" => 4 then substract 1 to get the index within the array 4 - 1 => 3
  const idx = (Number(curr.date.split("-")[1]) + shiftBy - 1) % 12;
  acc[idx] += curr.total;
  return acc
}, new Array(12).fill(0))

console.log(labelValues)
```

Comment: Yes i see that the current solution will work, but the thing is that i was doing a match upon my `generatedMonths` . As you can see generated months will look like this 
`generatedMonths = [Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May]` Because i am creating them based on today's month with a span of 1 year back. That's why i mentioned that my solution needs to look like `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 92.31, 68.65]`

Comment: I see. In that case what I would do is to map the values to their target position afterwards using simple modular arithmetic. Give me a second and I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hmm I do not actually understand the `const mapping` functionality. 
And also as you can see from my first example from above i generate my months based on `moment` . That being said `generatedMonths` is a dynamic array based on the current month. From my comment above i gave an example how would it look for this month. So i geuss `mapping` should be dynamic also ? Based on `generatedMonths` ?

Comment: No `mapping` will always be the same. You just need to change the first value in `generatedMonth` to whatever month you want to have and it will give you the correct result. The idea is simple: Normally i would map January to 0, February to 1, ... as in my first solution. Now, I look at the first value of generated Month: Assume it is December. Then what I need to do to get the correct result is shift all values to the right by one so I map December to 0, January to 1, ... And this works for every month. If it is February I need February to be as position 0, but currently january is there, so

Comment: I need to shift all value 11 places to the right which will result in February to 0, March to 1, ....